# How to get nth child in jquery of a new element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have created table row using jquery:

```
var tableRow = $("<tr>").append($("<td>").text("one"))
                        .append($("<td>").text("two"))
                        .append($("<td>").text("three"));
```

Now I add it to the table in the document:

```
$("#table_id").append(tableRow);
```

The next thing I want to do is to set the click events on some of the cells of the tableRow created above. I want to use nth child selector for that purpose. However from the documentation it seems that it is possible to use it with some selectors like :

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)")
```

But now I need to use  `:nth-child()` for a variable tableRow. 
How is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I want to use nth child selector for that purpose.

In that case, you can use `.find()`

```
cell = tableRow.find(':nth-child(2)');
cell.on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: While `find` works for the **specific** structure the OP mentioned (since the `td`s have no elements in them), the more general solution (still meeting the OP's odd "I want to use `:nth-child` requirement) would be `children` so you aren't getting **all** of the `:nth-child(2)` elements in the tree: https://jsfiddle.net/80tnutc8/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) along with [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
tableRow.find('td:nth-child(2)')
```

Or in this case you can use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/), which might be better

```
tableRow.children('nth-child(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.eq()` like

```
 $("#table_id tr td:eq(1)")
```

Or you can directly call from tableRow like

```
$(tableRow + "tr td:eq(1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your created the element dynamically so you have to use the following structure, if its statically created(ie: created in HTML you can use what your mention for ul)

```
$('#table_id').find(":nth-child(2n)")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vtvBj/)