# Selecting all the elements between nth-child and nth-last-child in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know in CSS if I wanted to select certain elements between lets say the 5th child and last I would put .class-name:nth-child(5) ~ nth-last-child.

So how would I go about doing this in Jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get nth child in jquery of a new element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268240/how-to-get-nth-child-in-jquery-of-a-new-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, I would try something like this:

```
$('.class-name:nth-child(5) ~ .class-name:not(:last-child)');
```

You can see a demo of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x6doax9u/).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what you mean by "between lets say the 5th child and last", but let's say you mean from the 5th element up to, but not including, the last one. You can do pretty flexible filtering like this using [`$().slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$('.class-name').slice(4, -1);
```